# Bot Uptime Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, uptime

I'm trying to get the uptime of my bot. Every time I run it whether on my desktop or on Heroku, all it gives me is "0" for all time formats.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const moment = require("moment");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
require("moment-duration-format");
module.exports = {
    name: 'stats',
    description: "Bot Stats",
    execute(message, args){ 
        const duration = moment.duration(bot.uptime).format(" D [days], H [hrs], m [mins], s [secs]");
        const statEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle("**  = STATISTICS =**")
            .addField("**Mem Usage  ::**", `**${(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2)} MB**`)
            .addField("**Uptime**", `**${duration}**`);
        message.channel.send(statEmbed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are create new Discord client in non main file? **1 token - 1 client**

You need run your command execute with `(message, args, bot)` and then you will got right uptime.

> Your bot arg has `undefined` property of `bot.uptime`, because you not
>   loggin in with that "new" Client.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it for my bot:
I used the `client.uptime()` module.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ + /);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'uptime') {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
        let totalSeconds = (client.uptime / 1000);
        let days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 86400);
        totalSeconds %= 86400;
        let hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
        totalSeconds %= 3600;
        let minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
        let seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds % 60);

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
           .setTitle(`Uptime`)
           .addField("Days", `${days}`)
           .addField("Hours", `${hours}`)
           .addField("Minutes", `${minutes}`)
           .addField("Seconds", `${seconds}`)
       message.channel.send(embed);
    }
});

client.login("YOUR TOKEN");
```